# Docusign ViewUrl: UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT error

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying out a simple example to get a pdf signed in docuSign, but I'm running into the UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT error when trying to get the ViewUrl to redirect the user.

Here is the code I'm using to to create the envelope with the pdf doc.

```
    string recipientName = "Tester";
    string recipientEmail = "test@me.com";
    string accountId = AuthenticateDocuSign();
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\test.pdf");


    EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
    envDef.EmailSubject = "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Please sign this doc";

    // Add a document to the envelope
    DocuSign.eSign.Model.Document doc = new DocuSign.eSign.Model.Document();
    doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
    doc.Name = "TestFile.pdf";
    doc.DocumentId = "1";

    envDef.Documents = new List<DocuSign.eSign.Model.Document>();
    envDef.Documents.Add(doc);

    // Add a recipient to sign the documeent
    Signer signer = new Signer();
    signer.Email = recipientEmail;
    signer.Name = recipientName;
    signer.RecipientId = "1";

    // Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign
    signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
    signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
    SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
    signHere.DocumentId = "1";
    signHere.PageNumber = "1";
    signHere.RecipientId = "1";
    signHere.XPosition = "100";
    signHere.YPosition = "100";
    signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);

    envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
    envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
    envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);

    // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
    envDef.Status = "sent";

    // |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to creating and sending Envelopes (aka signature requests)
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

    EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

    RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnURL,
        ClientUserId = "1000",  // must match clientUserId set in step #2!
        AuthenticationMethod = "email",
        UserName = recipientName,
        Email = recipientEmail, 
    };
    ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, viewOptions); // EXCEPTION!
```

Complete error:

> DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException was unhandled by user code
>   ErrorCode=400   HResult=-2146233088   Message=Error calling
>   CreateRecipientView: {   "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
>   "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient
>   of the specified envelope." }

Comment: Did you actually define the clientUserID of the recipient when creating this envelope? The triplet of name, email@, and clientUserID must match the recipient information provided during envelope creation in order to successfully create a recipient view.

Comment: @LuisScott: thanks, i had to add signer.ClientUserId = "1000". You should convert your comment to an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Luis indicates in the comment above, you must specify the **clientUserId** property for the signer in the **Create Envelope** request, if you want to be able to subsequently retrieve the "View" URL for that Recipient:

```
signer.clientUserId = 1000;
```

You can set the **clientUserId** property to any value you choose -- I used **1000** in this example because that's the value that your code is using in the **Post Recipient View** request.

```
ClientUserId = "1000",  // must match clientUserId set in step #2!
```

(The **clientUserId**, **name**, and **email** property values that you specify in the **Post Recipient View** request must exactly match the values that you specified for the Recipient in the **Create Envelope** request.)